# Collaboration between SVN repository and gitolite

Tags: svn, gitolite, collaboration

I plan to clone a directory of a remote SVN repository (with http access) into a **Gitolite** repository. I would like to give access of this Gitolite repository to former developers. Following the [Integration-Manager-Workflow](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows#Integration-Manager-Workflow),
the former developers clone this and make changes on their repo (*developersGitRepo*). After some time I merge the changes of the *developersGitRepo* into the *Gitolite repo*. After this the changes will be merged into the SVN repo. The SVN repo can only be accessed by internal developers.

I have a server called `GITOLITE_HOST` where I have installed Gitolite which is working. I want to make a copy of a remote SVN repository into a Gitolite repository called `gitolite@GITOLITE_HOST:testing` which I configured in the `gitolite.conf` file:

```
    repo testing
    RW+ = @all
```

Gitolite is installed and working so that I can checkout a repository with `git clone gitolite@HOST:testing`

Now my questions:

1. Is it correct, that subgit-2.0 is the perfect tool to use for this and synchronise SVN with Gitolite and vice versa?
2. The page at http://yellowseed.org/tutorials/svn-to-git.html is exactly what I want to do, but SVN has to be on the same server as Gitolite. What must I do to use http access for SVN?
3. What other options do I have? A description of the commands would be very helpful.

Comment: Have a look at this: [From SVN to Gitolite](http://blog.subgit.com/from-svn-to-gitolite/). Might give you some ideas.